# Cannot update my arraylist from adapter

Tags: android

I am working on this chat application. In that, I want to search particular message in recycler view. For that, I am using `Filterable` interface. When I try to update my `arraylist` with `notifydatasetchange()`, it is not changing the `arraylist` items. It remains as it is.

Here is my Adapter code.

**MessageAdapter.java**

```
package com.android.customizedchat;
import java.lang.*;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.Filter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.*;


public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Message> filteredmessageList;
    List<Message> messages;


    public MessageAdapter(List<Message> objects){
        this.messages = objects;
        this.filteredmessageList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Message message = messages.get(position);
        boolean myMsg=message.getIsMe();
        setAlingnment(holder,myMsg);
        holder.message.setText(message.getText());
        holder.user.setText(message.getName());
        holder.timestamp.setText(message.getTimestamp());
        System.out.println("From Holder: "+holder.message.getText());
    }


    public void setAlingnment(ViewHolder holder,boolean isMe){
        if(!isMe){

            holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            holder.user.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
            holder.timestamp.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

        }else {

            holder.message.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.user.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            holder.timestamp.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);


        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return messages.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public TextView message;
        public TextView user;
        public TextView timestamp;
        public ImageView message_image;

        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            message = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView);
            user = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            timestamp = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageTimeStamp);
            message_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.messageImageView);
        }

    }

    public Filter getFilter(){
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                System.out.println("Enter Filtering");
                String charString = constraint.toString();
                if(charString.isEmpty()){
                    filteredmessageList = messages;
                }
                else{
                    List<Message> filterlist = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Message row : messages){
                        if(row.getText().toLowerCase().contains(charString.toLowerCase())){
                            filterlist.add(row);
                        }
                    }
                    filteredmessageList = filterlist;
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredmessageList;
                System.out.println(filterResults.values.toString());
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                filteredmessageList = (ArrayList<Message>) results.values;
                for (int i = 0; i < filteredmessageList.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(filteredmessageList.get(i).getText());
                }
              //  notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


}
```

And here is my Main Activity File

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.android.customizedchat;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
import android.view.*;


import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.github.nkzawa.emitter.Emitter;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.IO;
import com.github.nkzawa.socketio.client.Socket;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView messageListView;
    public MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
    public EditText messageEditText;
    public Button messageSendButton;
    String TimeStamp="";
    public List<Message> message;

    private Socket socket;{
        try{
            socket = IO.socket("http://192.168.137.1:3000");
           // socket = IO.socket("https://customizedchat.herokuapp.com");
        }
        catch (URISyntaxException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public String username;
    //public String url_connect ="http://192.168.137.1/test/retrivemessage.php";
    public String url_connect = "http://wallstreet.000webhostapp.com/retrivemessage.php";
    //public String url_insert = "http://192.168.137.1/test/insertmessage.php";
    public String url_insert = "http://wallstreet.000webhostapp.com/insertmessage.php";
    public String uname,msgs,tstamp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String GroupID = bundle.getString("GroupID");
        final String GroupName = bundle.getString("GroupName");
        Toast.makeText(this, "ID"+GroupID+"Name"+GroupName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setTitle(GroupName);

        socket.connect();
        socket.emit("subscribe",GroupName);

        socket.on("newM",handleIncomingMessages);

        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",0);
        username=pref.getString("uname",null);

        messageListView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        messageListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        messageEditText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        messageSendButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.messageSendButton);

        message =new ArrayList<>();
        messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(message);
        messageListView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);

        messageSendButton.setEnabled(true);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_connect, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try{
                    String res = response;
                    JSONArray msgs = new JSONArray(res);
                    for(int i=0;i<msgs.length();i++){
                        JSONObject msg =(JSONObject) msgs.get(i);
                        String status = msg.getString("code");
                        if(status.equals("success")){
                            String mesg = msg.getString("Message");
                            String uname = msg.getString("Username");
                            String tstamp = msg.getString("TimeStamp");
                            Message message1 = new Message(mesg,uname,tstamp);
                            if(uname.equals(username))
                                message1.setMe(true);
                            addMessage(message1);
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The table for this group has been created in database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }catch (JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("grpname",GroupName);
                return params;
            }
        };
        Connection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


        messageSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!(messageEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))) {
                   // final String time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());\
                    Date dt = new Date();
                    long time = dt.getTime();
                    if (android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(MainActivity.this)) {
                        TimeStamp =  new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a", Locale.US).format(new Date(time));
                    }
                    else{
                        TimeStamp = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(new Date());
                    }
                    final String msg =messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    Message message = new Message(msg, username,TimeStamp);
                    message.setMe(true);
                   StringRequest insert = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url_insert, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }){
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                            Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                            params.put("grpname",GroupName);
                            params.put("message",msg);
                            params.put("username",username);
                            params.put("timestamp",TimeStamp);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };
                    Connection.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(insert);
                    String MESSAGGE = messageEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                    addMessage(message);
                    messageEditText.setText("");
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
                        object.put("message", MESSAGGE);
                        object.put("userid", username);
                        object.put("timestamp",TimeStamp);
                        object.put("room",GroupName);
                        socket.emit("newM", object);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    //for handeling incoming messages
    private Emitter.Listener handleIncomingMessages = new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Object... args) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data=(JSONObject) args[0];
                    String message,uname,tstamp;
                    try {
                        message=data.getString("message").toString().trim();
                        uname = data.getString("uname").toString();
                        tstamp = data.getString("tstamp").toString();
                        //System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------"+uname+" : "+message);
                        Message msg=new Message(message,uname,tstamp);
                        msg.setMe(false);
                        addMessage(msg);
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        return;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        socket.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);
        //SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) item.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                messageAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }

    public void addMessage(Message m){
        message.add(m);
        messageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(message);
        messageAdapter.notifyItemInserted(0);
        messageListView.scrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
    }
}
```

When I print the filtered values on the console, it prints perfect. But it doesn't update the list of the recycler view.

It will be really helpful if someone can get into this and help me find solution.

Comment: did the below answer help solve your question?  Please advise, as I have a similar use case.

Answer (score 0):

You must have to update the `message` list before notifying adapter, here in this method:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            messageAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return false;
        }
```